# Клонирование с selected у списков

Tags: javascript, jquery, form

есть список

```js
$(document).on("click", ".add", function(event){
    $(this)
          .parent()
          .clone()
          .appendTo(".l");

      if ( $(".t:last>.rem").size() == 0) {
        $(".t:last").append($('<input type="button" value="Удалить" class="rem">'));
      }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="l">
<div class="t">
<input type="text" name="callsign" class="call" placeholder="Callsign">
<select size="1" name="rst">
<option selected>Рапорт</option>
<option value="59">59</option>
<option value="58">58</option>
</select>
<select size="1" name="mode">
<option selected>Диапазон</option>
<option value="10">10 метров</option>
<option value="20">20 метров</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Копировать" class="add">
</div>
</div>
```

Выбираю мышкой в списке пункт option 58 жму кнопку клонировать
Скрипт клонирует список, но не клонирует атрибут selected.
Приходится при каждом копировании списка в нем выбирать, этого не нужно.
Помогите сделать так чтобы клонировался и выбранный пункт списка если он есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).on("click", ".add", function(event) {
  var node = $(this).parent()
  var cloned = node.clone().appendTo(".l")

  var originalSelects = node.find('select');
  cloned.find('select').each(function(index, item) {
    $(item).val(originalSelects.eq(index).val());

  });
  if ($(".t:last>.rem").size() == 0) {
    $(".t:last").append($('<input type="button" value="Удалить" class="rem">'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="l">
  <div class="t">
    <input type="text" name="callsign" class="call" placeholder="Callsign">
    <select size="1" name="rst">
      <option selected>Рапорт</option>
      <option value="59">59</option>
      <option value="58">58</option>
    </select>
    <select size="1" name="mode">
      <option selected>Диапазон</option>
      <option value="10">10 метров</option>
      <option value="20">20 метров</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" value="Копировать" class="add">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю !!!. Что то подобное видел в инете но не сообразил как приделать. Очень сэкономили время и нервы )